# Loop through all posted articles and print specific section

Tags: 8

I am trying to create my first Drupal 8 theme. On the frontpage, I want to list all articles with the title, summary, date posted, etc.

I more or less achieved this using views. Basically {{ page.content }} in twig, but found it to be really inflexible and I didn't really get the results that I wanted. What I want to do is just to iterate through all the articles and print each section of that article "manually". For instance:

```
{% for page in pages %}
  {{ page.content.title }}
  {{ page.content.datePosted }}
  {{ page.content.body }}
{% endfor %}
```

So that I can have more control of what is happening and not making a lot of configuration in the views module when deploying. What is the best soltuion to achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: Please don't do it like that. Drupal isn't WordPress. Try to leave the templates as untouched as possible and simply create a view listing all articles in a certain view mode (let's say Teaser view mode), then go the Articles' "manage display" screen, choose the view mode and adjust the fields you wanna show. **Using page level templates to list nodes should be considered bad practice.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get all nodes of a specific content type and print the data of each node inside page.html.twig](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/279353/get-all-nodes-of-a-specific-content-type-and-print-the-data-of-each-node-inside)

Comment: Create a view, set the filters, set the limit, drop it in a region.