# How can I loop through all article content types and get the content of each

Tags: theming, nodes

I created a new article content and am overriding that by creating a template for it (ie: node--4.html.twig).

Then inside this template, I want to loop through all nodes that belong to article content type; and to achieve that, I created my .theme file and added the following code based on the answer for this question [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/279353/get-all-nodes-of-a-specific-content-type-and-print-the-data-of-each-node-inside):

```
<?php
  function capoeira_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  $articles = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')->condition('type', 'article')->execute();
  $nodes = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::loadMultiple($articles);  
  $variables['articles'] = $nodes;
}
```

Inside the template I do have:

```
{{ kint(articles) }}
```

inside my template and I go refresh the page I show article as NULL.

How do I loop through the articles?

EDITED:

None of the below work:

```
function capoeira_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  $articles = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')->condition('type', 'article')->execute();
  $nodes = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::loadMultiple($articles);
  $variables['name'] = $nodes;
}

function capoeira_preprocess_node(&$variables){
  $variables['name'] = 'My name comes here';
}

function capoeira_preprocess_node_article(&$variables){
  $variables['name'] = 'My name comes here';
}
```

Comment: Leaving out the fact a theme should not have code that queries entities, as that is code for a module, did you check the theme to which you added that code is the theme used for the page? Are you using the correct machine name in those hooks? The fact you show a function with a name starting with `scottishleader_` and two with a name starting with `capoeira_` makes me wonder you are prefixing the function names with the wrong theme machine name.

Comment: It's also not clear why, for every page Drupal shows with that theme, you would show a list of nodes or data obtained from that list of nodes.

Comment: @kiamlaluno , the themename is capoeira, inside it, I have a file named capoeira.theme, which has the preprocess functions. I want to add the functionality for my node--4.html.twig template, which is used to show all the news(news are from article content type). Hope I could explain better

Comment: You should also show the code you are using in the template file to loop through the list of nodes. If that code is wrong, we cannot tell you how to fix it without seeing it.

Comment: Then, as usual, if you are editing the code of an enabled theme, you need to first clear Drupal cache, or Drupal will not notice there are new hooks in the code. That, or first disable the theme, before adding new hooks.

Comment: Why do you need to loop through all of these in the 1st place? This is going to slow ur page load as the number of articles grow...

Comment: @NoSssweat it will only slow the page if one decides to show 100 articles

Comment: You could just create a block using views and either assign it to the page (via block layout and visibility settings) or embed the block entity as a reference field in the node itself. This eliminates much of the preprocessing and likely can eliminate a one-off node template.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_node_article(&$variables){
  $node = $variables['node'];
   $nid = $node->id();
   // similarly you can fetch other fields
}
```

then override article content type as `node--article.html.twig`
and pass data to twig file

Comment: I initially had HOOK_preprocess_node and the result was the same. I now tried to modify the template name as per your answer but still no success.

Comment: @deSousa see updated answer

Comment: I just edited my question. My understanding is that you choose the name after "preprocess" based on the template name in usage, whether its a page, node or node type. If so is true, then using soccer_preprocess_node should work because my template name is node--4.html.twig, which redundantly speaking its node. Anyway, nothing is working for some odd reason.