# Target individual items of a multi-value field in my page template

Tags: 8, theming

I created one field for an image and In the field setting, I made allowed number of values to 2 (please find the attached screenshot

[image])

So my question is, how can I add both the images in a different div tag in my page template.

Or, how can I target first and second image in my page template.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Can you please update your question and add the code you are currently using to print this field inside what template exactly? Many thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Render a node field inside page.html.twig](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/188122/render-a-node-field-inside-page-html-twig)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this. Given you use a custom or sub-theme you'd follow [Twig Template naming conventions](http://Twig%20Template%20naming%20conventions) and create your own `field--node--MYFIELDNAME.html.twig` template. And then simply adjust the markup according your needs.

See Classy's [`field.html.twig`](https://github.com/drupal/drupal/blob/8.8.x/core/themes/classy/templates/field/field.html.twig) for reference and its for-loop you simply can customize:

```
{% for item in items %}
  <div{{ attributes.addClass(classes, 'field__item') }}>
    {{ item.content }}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

---

To target the second item in a multi-value field inside `page.html.twig` use the following snippet (it starts to count with `0`, so that `0` is the first and `1` is the second item).

```
{{ node.field_MYFIELD.1.value }}
```